# How to Resolve Unexpected token error in react render. Did you mean `{'{'` or `&brace;`?

Tags: reactjs

Please help me resove the errors in the following code. I have tried several times but top avail.

```
import React from "react";

export class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="base-container">
      <div className="header">Login</div>
      <div className="content"></div>
      <div className="form">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='footer'>
          <button type="button" className="btn">
              Login
          </button>
    </div>
    );
   }
}
```

**error:**

```
Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'{'` or `&brace;`?
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfzLv.jpg)

Comment: You are missing out one of the closing `</div>` tags after `</button>`.

Answer (score 1):

your footer div is not closed. Please close that `</div>`